# Soldiers picked up by a time traveling ship to fight for one particular timeline to occur

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I know this is a long shot but I'm looking for the name of a book I read when I was younger (early 70's).  From what I recall, the main story was a bunch of soldiers got picked up by a time traveling ship from various periods of time in order to form a unit which would fight for one particular time line to occur.  Snippets I remember are the climax where the good and evil sides are fighting invisibly around a young farm boy; one side wanting him to pick up a magnet and the other a rock.  The soldiers from the evil side are insect shaped.  The main hero (one of the soldiers) falls in love with the woman leader from the future.  In one time line she is good and in the other evil.  I seem to recall is being called A (something) In Time but that could be wrong.  I know this isn't a lot to go on but if it strikes a familiar chord in someone's memory, I'd appreciate any info you could pass along.

Comment: a ..... (something) in time ? Stitch would be the obvious answer; http://www.isfdb.org

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I agree, Stitch is the obvious way to go but that wasn't it.  I'm not positive the "a (something) in time" title is even right but it's the piece that got stuck in my brain.  Thanks also for the pointer to the isfdb.org page.  Lots of stuff there I can pore through!

Comment: The something (legion) in (of) time. You were close

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the titular story from the anthology "[The Legion of Time](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/898049.The_Legion_of_Time)" by Jack Williamson

It's described [here](http://yellowedandcreased.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/the-legion-of-time-jack-williamson/):

> *Their mission is the penultimate butterfly effect:*
>
> **A boy in the Ozarks
> will come to a Jonbar Hinge, and must choose between picking up a
> magnet or a pebble. If he picks up the magnet, it’ll trigger a
> life-long interest in science, which will result in the serene future
> utopia of Jonbar.**
>
> **If he picks up the pebble, it’ll lead to him
> breaking windows or killing birds with it or something, culminating
> with the despotic tyranny of Gyronch.**
>
> Sorainya, of course, has stolen
> the magnet, and it’s up to our brave heroes to return it.

[image]

Comment: That's it!!!  Thank you so much!  I did a little googling and found the cover of the copy I read.  So very cool.  Now to go find it and read it again!  Thanks to all for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Okay,

After reviewing several literature story lines from here:

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TimePolice

The Story that I think most closely sounding to yours might be The Corridors Of Time by Poul Annderson, 1965, reviewed here:

http://www.sfreviews.net/corridors.html

No mention of the enemies being insect shaped, but perhaps technological might be described that way. I haven't read it so I can't be sure.

He also wrote a series called Time Patrol which describes similar issues

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TimePatrol

Originally when you described I thought of Ben Bova's Orion series, which has a time traveling warrior, preventing humanity's destruction and meeting his love in new forms each time (one being a future commander), but I don't think he had a specific enemy faction.

https://www.goodreads.com/series/51197-orion

Hope one of those is it, please let me know if you found it. I also hope the TV Tropes link helps you find more, as that's how I find new series I might like based on prior series I enjoyed.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It wasn't one of those but you gave me a few more places to look.  I'll keep digging!